# Process Big Spatial Data

Tags: openstreetmap, jts

In my project, I'm using `JTS` library. I have huge `OSM` files to read and process for various operations like intersection of an area with a point....etc.

Are there any data structures or methods to do some parallel processing because I have huge data set ?

Comment: sorry, what is the "JTS" library? the namespace is crowded with Jewish Theological Seminary results

Comment: Usually you use a DB with geospatial extension as PostgreSQL+PostGIS for example.

Comment: @boulder_ruby The JTS library is a java library for geometric operations. There's also a wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite. And the "jts" tag in the question has an explanation linked with it, too.